# MDI child form problem in C#

Tags: c#, mdichild

When I maximize 1 MDI child form, all MDI child forms would be maximized too. Is it possible to have 1 form maximized and another one not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A maximized MDI child form should occupy the entire child area and so the state of the other children should not really matter as they are not visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see a maximized window with another smaller window in front of it, I think some kind of user interface with docking and floating panels would be a better choice. Something like the way it works in Visual Studio.

Creating custom MDI/Non-MDI functionality is very time consuming and frustrating work, and the end result can be confusing to users who are used to standard MDI.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.  Only thing you can do is to set the window in front non MDI and taskbar = no

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you CAN do this -  use the API Call SetParent instead of setting .MDIParent.

Answer (score 0):

The Maximized Form will need to be an MDI Child called with `Child1.Show()`.

The non-Maximized Form will need to NOT be an MDI Child called with `Form1.Show(this)` or `Form1.ShowDialog(this)`.